# How do I check what filesystem my SVN repository is using?

Tags: svn, filesystems, berkeley-db, fsfs

I've already created my repository and have been using it for a while. I wanted to check what filesystem data store it is using: Berkeley DB or FSFS. I'm not sure how to check this. I've looked at svnadmin, svnlook, etc. Any hints on how to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check the `db/fs-type` file in your repository:

```
$ cat db/fs-type
fsfs
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you can access the filesystem the repository is on then you can check if there is a file for each source file in the DB subdir

Sorry don't know how to do it from the client side

Answer (score 0):

Granted this is an older question, but if you have access to the server, it is possible to examine the details using `svnadmin`. Change to the directory containing the repositories, and then use `svnadmin info REPOSITORY`. The `Filesystem Type` and `Filesystem Format` will be displayed. Works with `svnadmin` version from at least 1.9.

**# svnadmin info sandbox**

```
Path: sandbox
UUID: c9ff7519-0e7a-4f99-8b60-b23157107fec
Revisions: 0
Repository Format: 5
Compatible With Version: 1.9.0
Repository Capability: mergeinfo
Filesystem Type: fsfs
Filesystem Format: 7
FSFS Sharded: yes
FSFS Shard Size: 1000
FSFS Shards Packed: 0/0
FSFS Logical Addressing: yes
Configuration File: sandbox/db/fsfs.conf
```